# Rails: How to send parameter from View to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller, haml

I want to click a heading and then sort the elements below it.
So I have added link_to like this:

```
%th= link_to "Title"
```

after this I need to add parameter to send to my controller to sort the list. How do I add parameters? say the list needs to be sorted by "title" of the object.

And which function in my controller will receive the parameter?

I am a newbie so having trouble n tracing the data flow.

Comment: title is the column in your table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add querystring parameters to link\_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to)

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari: yes

Comment: then try this http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Ruby table by column headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408660/how-to-sort-ruby-table-by-column-headers)

Comment: Maybe somthing like  %th= link_to "Title", your_path(sort: "desc")

Answer (score 1):

```
link_to "Search Sort", index_path(:sort => "asc", :column => "title")
#=> <a href="/sort?sort=true&amp;column=test">Search Sort</a>
```

Comment: After this what to check in def index of my controller?
Or does any other method gets called in my controller?

Comment: Please follow [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order), for ordering the column